# Kafka - Long running job decreases through put

Tags: apache-kafka

I have three partitions and three consumers in my consumer group.

Job A, B assigned to partition1
Job C, D assigned to partition2
Job E, F assigned to partition3

Job C,D,E,F took less than 20 seconds to complete but job A is taking 30 minutes to complete. B if executed will take 10 seconds to complete but got stuck behind A. B will have to wait 30 minutes although two consumers are just sitting idle.

How do I solve this and not get B stuck if there are consumers sitting idle.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really something Kafka can solve. Plus, you cannot have more than one consumer on any partition, so "A, B" is really just "A" from a consumer-group perspective.  You'd need to decouple your "processing" logic that is blocking from the event consumption if you want to "increase throughput", with the tradeoff of skipping, duplicating, or handling events out of order.

As one example, `methodA(record)` does a thing, and takes 30 minutes. That's completely unrelated to Kafka, as you've executed a blocking function. Without more details, you'll simply need to re-write this to not block as long. Otherwise, do something like `new Thread(() => methodA(record)).start()` (run it in the background, and keep consuming, and starting more threads).

But, when complete, sends to `A-completed` topic, which "consumer B" then reads and runs `methodB(recordFromA)`.